# Is Innodb Cluster synchronous?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I was reading the [InnoDB Cluster page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html), but I did not find any information stating whether it's synchronous or not. Is it configurable to work in either synchronous or asynchronous mode?

I currently have a master-master topology using MySQL version 5.7, and I'm planning to upgrade to MySQL version 8. However, I want to upgrade and create a topology with a synchronous mode option with multi-primary.

Comment: See [Introducing MySQL InnoDB Cluster – MySQL HA: Out-of-Box, Easy to use High Availability](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/introducing-mysql-innodb-cluster-mysql-ha-out-of-box-easy-to-use-high-availability/#:~:text=By%20leveraging%20the%20new%20Group,and%20built%2Din%20automatic%20failover.)

Comment: You have several "requirements"; please explain the need for each fo we can better advise you.  (sync + async; multi-primary; etc)

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB Cluster uses Group Replication, which is essentially [asynchronous out of the box](https://lefred.be/content/mysql-group-replication-synchronous-or-asynchronous-replication). It's synchronous up to the point where the binlogs are sent to the secondary instances. After that, by default, the transaction is a success even though the secondary instances haven't fully applied the changes in the binlogs received from the primary instance.

You can change that behaviour with the [group_replication_consistency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-configuring-consistency-guarantees.html) variable.